# How do I attach AWS_IAM to the $default route of an API Gateway V2 using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

Here is my code

```
# HTTP API
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "api" {
    name          = local.apigw_name
    protocol_type = "HTTP"
    target        = aws_lambda_function.function.arn
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "default_route" {
  api_id            = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  route_key         = "$default"
  authorization_type = "AWS_IAM"   # <- THE IMPORTANT PART

  # modify the integration settings
  target = aws_lambda_function.function.arn
}
```

I get the following error message. I can make this work via the AWS console or AWS CLI but not with Terraform.

```
│ Error: error creating API Gateway v2 route: ConflictException: Route with key $default already exists for this API
│ 
│   with aws_apigatewayv2_route.default_route,
│   on main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "default_route":
│   20: resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "default_route" {
```

Comment: Note that I do not have a Route resource with key $default, so I assume that is create by default. So the question is: how do I attach AWS_IAM authorization to this route?

Comment: According to the documentation here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_route#route_key the `$default` can be specified just like you are doing, so if it already exists it may be because you already created the API before adding the default route to Terraform. You might need to import the route at this point, to allow Terraform to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it it possible in Terraform.  There is an AWS CLI [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-access-control-iam.html)

```bash
aws apigatewayv2 update-route \
    --api-id abc123 \
    --route-id abcdef \
    --authorization-type AWS_IAM
```

which you can try to run in a `local-exec`:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "api" {
  name          = local.apigw_name
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  target        = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.arn

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      "RouteId=$(aws apigatewayv2 get-routes --api-id ${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id} | jq -r '.Items[0].RouteId')"
      "aws apigatewayv2 update-route --api-id ${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id} --route-id $RouteId --authorization-type AWS_IAM"
    EOT
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, this would be a major bummer, I can't believe this was overlooked by terraform team. If the local-exec is the only workaround, I will accept this as a "solution" later. I mean all I want to do is to spin up an API gateway that would provide a special handle for catch all.